# how can we have different functions on ANt design menu items in the new version?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm sure if you're using ant design menu component you've got the same error:

> Warning: [antd: Menu] `children` will be removed in next major version. Please use `items` instead.

the new way to make this is:

```
const items = [
  { label: 'item 1', key: 'item-1' },
  { label: 'item 2', key: 'item-2' },
  {
    label: 'sub menu',
    key: 'submenu',
    children: [{ label: 'item 3', key: 'submenu-item-1' }],
  },
];
return <Menu items={items} />
```

and you can define your function and use it like this:

```
return <Menu onClick={onClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```

how can i have different functions on my items?

i'll be glad if someone help me with this

in the old way i could easily define any functions i want on any items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we can add functions to the items array as well

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState();

const func = () => {
   setCurrent(e.key);
}

const func2 = () => {
   setCurrent(e.key);
}

const items = [
  { 
    label: 'item 1', 
    key: 'item-1' 
    onClick: func,
    className: class1,
  },
  { 
    label: 'item 1', 
    key: 'item-1' 
    onClick: func2,
    className: class2,
  },,
  {
    label: 'sub menu',
    key: 'submenu',
    children: [{ label: 'item 3', key: 'submenu-item-1' }],
  },
];


return <Menu selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```